# Watir-Webdriver text_field deprecation - use textarea (but method does not seem to work)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, watir-webdriver

The new version of **watir-webdriver (0.8.0)** has been released. I have installed it and have been running my suites to check for changes. During this process I have noticed the text_field methods I am using to set text in `<input id="some_id" type="text">` tags has been deprecated from the message `Locating textareas with '#text_field' is deprecated. Please, use '#textarea' method instead.` I changed the `text_field` method to `textarea`, but once I do this the element can no longer be located.

Am I using the method wrong? I tried to use it as `browser.textarea(:id=> 'some_id').when_present.set "Text"`. Once the method times out, I get the message saying the element with the tagname `textarea` could not be located. Was wondering if there is something else I need the do to use the `textarea` method to set text in a `<input id="some_id" type="text">` tag.

**EDITED** => html I am trying to automate on:

```
<form action="some_href" method="post">
  <p class="align">
    <label for="user">Username</label>
    <input id="login" type="text" value="">
  </p>
  <p class="align">
    <label for="pass">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" value="">
  </p>
</form>
```

**EDITED** Watir code used to automate page

```
#RUBY CODE
class Login

  def open
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
    @browser.goto some_website_url #URL leading to page with form HTML above
  end

  def login_as
    user_field.when_present(10).set username
    password_field.when_present(10).set password
    login_link.when_present(10).click
  end

  def user_field
    @browser.text_field(:id=> "login")
  end

  def password_field
    @browser.text_field(:id=> 'password')
  end

  def username
    "user123"
  end

  def password
    "p@ssw0rd"
  end

  def login_link
    @browser.link(:text=> 'Sign-in')
  end
end#Login

#STEP DEFINITION
Given(/^login to website$/) do
  login = Login.new
  login.open
  login.login_as
end
```

The previous versions I have been using without the deprecation message is:

**watir-webdriver (0.6.11)**

**selenium-webdriver (2.44.0)**

Any answers would be appreciated if someone has some insight on the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the warning is occurring for that element? The warning only gets raised if you use the `text_field` method to locate a `textarea` element. In other words, the warnings is for `<textarea id="some_id">` not for `<input id="some_id" type="text">`.

Comment: Yes I am sure the warning is for `<input id="some_id" type="text">` and not `<textarea id="some_id">` I have double checked. I can post the html if you need me to.

Comment: I inputted both of the text fields using `browser.text_field(id: 'login').when_present.set 'text'` and `browser.text_field(id: 'password').when_present.set 'text'`, neither of which gave the deprecation warning. I was using v0.8.0 with Chrome and Firefox. What is the Watir code that you are running for this HTML that generates the warning?

Comment: I have added the watir code I use @Justin Ko.

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot reproduce the error given that HTML and Watir/Cucumber code. Looking at the [Watir-Webdriver code](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/text_field_locator.rb#L86-L90), I really do not see how the warning would be raised for an input element. When you see the warning you are only running this one single step?

Comment: No I running this step as a Background for other Scenarios that perform other functions.

Comment: Then I would guess that the warning is coming from one of those other functions. Please extract a runnable example that allows us to see the warning.

Comment: @Justin Ko - I uninstalled the watir-webdriver (0.8.0) and selenium-webdriver (2.46) gems and reinstalled them and the message for the deprecated text_field is not displaying anymore. Seems like something happened when I installed the gem. Thank you for the effort in trying to solve my issue. If the problem occurs again I will come back to this question.